# Troubleshooting SSH issues over secondary IP address

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, networking

** added IP info

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server with the following physical configuration:

- 1 eth for management
- 4 eth bonded for serving media locally

Initial setup was done via SSH over the Ethernet management link. I configured it with a static IP address and things ran smoothly.

I then configured the bond with a vlan interface and static IP address on the vlan. I am able to SSH to the vlan.

I then changed the IP of the Ethernet management link to a separate /31 network and configured a routing policy to use a default route when the management link was receiving traffic.

Now, I am able to SSH into my VLAN IP with no issues. I am also able to SSH into my management link, however after ~30 seconds, the SSH session hangs, and then another 30 seconds later the remote side unexpectedly closes the session. I am assuming this is a routing issue of some kind or SSH config tweak, but not sure how to troubleshoot. journalctl -f doesn't record any event when the session hangs or closes.  Thanks for any thoughts.

Here is my netplan config and some ip output:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.3.1/31]
      #gateway4:
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.3.0
          metric: 500
          table: 1
      routing-policy:
          - from: 192.168.3.1
            table: 1
    enp4s0f0:
      dhcp4: no
    enp4s0f1:
      dhcp4: no
    enp4s0f2:
      dhcp4: no
    enp4s0f3:
      dhcp4: no

network:
  version: 2
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: no
      interfaces:
        - enp4s0f0
        - enp4s0f1
        - enp4s0f2
        - enp4s0f3
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
        primary: enp4s0f0

network:
  version: 2
  vlans:
    bond0.2022:
      dhcp4: no
      id: 2022
      link: bond0
      addresses: [192.168.1.239/23]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.1]

~$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev bond0.2022 proto static
192.168.0.0/23 dev bond0.2022 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.250
192.168.3.0/31 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.3.1
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown

$ ip route show dev enp0s31f6 table 1
default via 192.168.3.1 proto static metric 500
default via 192.168.3.0 proto static metric 500

~$ ip a | grep UP
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
2: enp4s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
3: enp4s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
4: enp4s0f2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
5: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
6: enp4s0f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
7: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
8: bond0.2022@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
9: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000

C:\tracert 192.168.1.250

Tracing route to 192.168.1.250 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.250

Trace complete.

C:\tracert 192.168.3.1

Tracing route to 192.168.3.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.241
  3    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.3.1

Trace complete.
```

Comment: are all the x.x.x.1 appearing in the configuration all the same? If they are not the same obfuscating as you did won't help. Try [RFC 5737](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737) instead.

Comment: Good point. No, different subnets,  0.0/23 and 3.0/31. I’ll provide more details in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue. I have two routed interfaces on the client side subnet --a firewall and a router for remote networks. The firewall is the default gateway, but the router is the next-hop for the remote network I am using for management. I added a static route in my client for the remote network to the router next-hop instead of the default gateway, and the SSH session no longer closes.